# Firefox: Failure"nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)

Tags: ajax, firefox, cross-browser

I faced with following error in Firefox 23(this code works fine in IE and Chrome) during send of `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: <unknown filename> :: loadUiDesXml :: line 1" data: no] { message="Failure", result=2147500037, name="NS_ERROR_FAILURE", more...}
```

I can't google what `2147500037` error means and this error is very strange for me.
This is a piece of code:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (typeof theFile === "string") {
    xmlHttp.open("POST", theFile, false);
} else {
    xmlHttp.open("POST", theFile.baseURI, false);
}
xmlHttp.send("");
```

This code is executed from "onload" handler for body element.

The file variable is "`/emWeb_6-0/des/en/ld117/ept.xml`", domen origin policy shouldn't prevent this request. 
The most strange thing, that I can recieve ept.xml in other pages.

For example,  I can recieve this file successfully in the following scenario:

1. Recieve ept.xml file on page1.
2. Redirect to page2, recieve ept.xml again
3. Redirect to page3, recieve some other files, including ept.xml
4. Redirect back to page1, recieve status.xml, then I try to recieve ept.xml and I get error duting send("")

The network trace is the following:

```
POST ept.xml
POST ept.xml
POST pch.xml
POST node.xml
POST ftpRslt.xml
POST ept.xml
POST status.xml
POST status.xml
```

I can't execute `xmlHttp.send("")` here.

This code works inside frame, I think that it can be related with the error.
Can anyone explain what is the root cause of this?

**UPDATE:** Found, that there is error in HTTP response for this file:
XML syntax analysis error : address: moz-nullprincipal:{48eaaeb4-b5f1-4557-931a-88cfd0c372c5} Line 1, char2:

But I can resend thhis request and it works after that.